# Screw placement to tighten and eliminate squeaks and popping

Tags: stairs

I am installing some pre made,stick on adhesive carpeted stair tread covers and want to run some screws in before to tighten up and eliminate some squeaks and popping from the top since I have no access to underside....but I cant find a single screw or nail head to use as a guide for were to run screws in....I can figure out were for the front screws that will go into the riser....but on the sides and back edge is were I need a suggestion? I dont wanna just start runnin screws in and guessing,cause if the screw doesnt grab anything underneath its pointless? I appreciate any advice.

Comment: A couple relevant related questions: [What can be done to fix a squeak in stairs?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/132/157)  [Squeaky stairs, fix from below?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/108235/157)

Comment: How long ago did you purchase this home?  Did you use an inspector that works for YOU?  They go through stuff like this and their payment is minuscule compared with the big picture...such as 150 to 250 bucks?  Big deal.  Get one on board even after purchase, you might still be able to recoup under discovery rules.  You HAVE to be able to see ALL of your home before purchase!!  Drainage, basement, underlayment, asphalt emulsion on foundation, roofing structure and condition, ventilation!!  Very big deal.  Squeaky stairs means one thing!  Poor support and or deteriorating stringers.

Answer (score 1):

Gotta look at different ways to build step structure/risers. Get an idea of the different methods... 90 percent of the time the stringers are made from cutout 2X12's.  One on either side next to the edge and one in the middle. A stud finder is cheap and valuable.  Once you figure out the skeleton of your stair construction you will be able to do all of them. If you are covering your steps who cares about extra holes?  Shoot there are cool screws that pull the connecting wood towards the top wood...arghhh.  Can not believe I can't remember the name...we use 'Power Pro' .  Oh well, ask at your contractor supply store.  I would heartily recommend NOT using stick on carpeting for your treads!!

Comment: Yeah, I'd start punching holes with a 1/8" drill bit and see what you find.